# Implement logical OR for types within switch

Tags: go, types, interface

I have a `[]interface{}` I am iterating over, and checking the type of each element within a switch. I would like to add a 'catch-all' case for any of several numeric types, i.e. `int || float32 || float64`.

It seems we are able to check whether an element is of a single distinct type, but I have not been able to figure out the syntax for checking multiple types with `||` (or).

Is this possible? What I've tried ([Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/eyaHqufoDTA)):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    things := []interface{}{"foo", 12, 4.5, true}

    for _, thing := range things {

        switch t := thing.(type) {

        // How can we implement logical OR for types to implement a catch-all for numerics?
        // Throws error: "type <type> is not an expression"
        // case ( int || float64 ) :
        //  fmt.Printf("Thing %v is a 'numeric' type: %T\n", thing, t)


        // Single discrete types work fine, of course
        case string :
            fmt.Printf("Thing %v is of type: %T\n", thing, t)   
        case int :
            fmt.Printf("Thing %v is of type: %T\n", thing, t)
        case float64 :
            fmt.Printf("Thing %v is of type: %T\n", thing, t)
        case bool :
            fmt.Printf("Thing %v is of type: %T\n", thing, t)
        default :
            fmt.Printf("Thing %v is of unknown type\n", thing)
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 29):

Well, I thought you couldn't, until I [read the spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Switch_statements). You can, and it works just like multiple cases in any other `switch` in Go:

```
case bool, string:
    printString("type is bool or string")  // type of i is type of x (interface{})
```

Comment: Very helpful, thank you @Adrian. I feel silly, as I'll often see questions like mine and thing 'gee, go read the docs', but I was searching for 'type' - related docs, not thinking to look at switch. Feel like half of improving is shrewd doc hunting ability :)

Comment: One of my favorite things about Go is it's so simple you can read the spec in an hour or two. Of course, retaining all the details is a different matter entirely!

Answer (score 10):

Yes, it's possible.  But then `t` has the type of `interface{}` in any compound `case`s or in the `default` case.

```
switch t := v.(type) {
case string:
    // t is of type string
case int, int64:
    // t is of type interface{}, and contains either an int or int64
default:
    // t is also of type interface{} here
}
```

Comment: Oh goodness, simple!

Here's a 'gotcha' - if we if we have:
case int, int64
we cannot check for just
case int
later down the switch.

Thanks @Flimzy!

Comment: @gpanda That's not a gotcha of this kind of switch, but of every Go switch. Whenever if finds a match it won't check the next cases. `passthrough` and `goto` can be used to aleviate this. Are you interested in this? I can give you an example but i need more space than a comment for this. Won't post it as an answer if you don't need it as it won't offer anything additional to the existing answers.

Comment: @Adirio: I think you mean `fallthrough`, but fallthrough doesn't work on type switches.

Comment: `fallthrough` yes, sorry about the typo. Does it not work on type switches? I didn't know that. Well I guess we all learn something new each day.

Comment: I tried it in the playground to add to this answer, and was promptly told by the compiler that fallthrough is not allowed for type switches :)

Comment: I guesses I should also use the playground to check and look what I found: https://play.golang.org/p/3EI6ZxFfuvQ. It has nothing to do with `fallthrough`. The compound cases for type switches do transform into the proper type. Well they print as if they do at least.

Comment: Well that's two things then, I had never printed the type of an interface before, never needed to. When I have this kind of cases they are usually not on builtin types and I usually build an interface for them.

Comment: @Adirio: fmt.Printf does its own type assertion/reflection to get at the underlying type, even though `t` is of type `interface{}` still, in that compound case.